# Raabitmq: Ranch listener rabbit_web_dispatch_sup_15672 had connection process started with cowboy_protocol

Tags: rabbitmq, queue, message-queuing

**Getting these in the logs in rabbitmq node: node1.**

- `Ranch listener rabbit_web_dispatch_sup_15672 had connection process started with cowboy_protocol:start_link/4 at <0.31197.2720> exit with reason: [{reason,{timeout,{gen_server,call,...`
- `Ranch listener rabbit_web_dispatch_sup_15672 had connection process started with cowboy_protocol:start_link/4 at <0.29846.2766> exit with reason: {[{reason,function_clause},{mfa,{rabbit_shovel_mgmt,to_json,2}}...`

**Next node is down**

- `Management delegate query returned errors:
  [{<32932.3001.0>,{exit,{nodedown,'rabbit@**node1**'},[]}}]`
- `=INFO REPORT==== 7-May-2019::08:51:10 ===
  node 'rabbit@**node1**' down: net_tick_timeout`

Not able to debug what exactly is causing it. RMQ node went down because of this error or any other factor is responsible for the same?